# RegEx: Match {{#if}}...{{/if}} Tags

Tags: regex, tags, handlebars.js

To match only `{{#if}}...{{/if}}` tags via regex is easy. But what do I do, when the content of this tag might also contain various IF-Tags like:

```
{{#if name}}
    Hello {{name}},
    {{#if age}}
        You are {{age}} years old.
    {{/if}}
{{/if}}
```

My approach fails: http://www.regexr.com/39s9k

```
/(?:{{#if(?: *))(.*)(?: *)}}([\s\S]*?)(?:{{\/if}})/g
```

its suppossed to match the whole IF-block. From top to bottom, including the IF in between

Comment: what's wrong with your regex? What's your expected output?

Comment: sorry, i didnt make that clear: its suppossed to match the whole IF-block. From top to bottom, including the IF in between

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)... what are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: I just want to match a whole IF-Block. At the moment, he matches the first `{{/if}}` from the IF-Block in between. I want to avoid that.

Comment: You're using JS, right? Then forget about it because JS regexes are too weak. You'd need either recursion or balancing groups to achieve this with regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone who is still searching for a solution to this problem:
I couldnt do it with JS-RegEx, so I did it like this:

- Search all `{{#if ...}}`-tags inside the string

  ```
  /(?:{{#if(?: *))(.*)(?: *)}}/g
  ```
- Replace the matches with `{##0##}`, one index for each tag. Also save the statement (`$1`) to an array, to access it later via its index.
- Iterate through the array **backwards** and do this for each item:

  ```
  str = str.replace(new RegExp('{##'+i+'##}([\\s\\S]*?){{\\/if}}', 'g'), "{##"+i+"##}$1{##/"+ i +"##}");
  ```

  What it does is replacing all `{{/if}}`-end-tags with its matching number.
  For this step, iterating backwards is really important.
- Now you can match/replace the tags with

  ```
  /{##(\d)##}([\s\S]*){##\/\1##}/g
  ```